# Unable to receive something in PHP from XMLHttpRequest's "POST"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

First off, here's my code:

HTML ("formdata-index-test.html"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>   
<form id="the-form" method="post" action="formdata-validation-test.php">
    <input type="text" id="the-text">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<script src="formdata-fields-control-test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS ("formdata-fields-control-test.js"):

```
var form = document.getElementById("the-form");

form.onsubmit = function() {
var q = document.getElementById("the-text").value;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200)) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open("POST", "formdata-validation-test.php", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send("q="+q);
}
```

PHP ("formdata-validation-test.php"):

```
<?php
$example = $_POST['q'];

echo $example;

if (empty($example)) {
        echo "Empty";
}
?>
```

Now, at the beginning, I wasn't getting anything as response, but after a few tries and changes in my code, I'm being able to receive that alert in the JS file. The weird thing is that, even receiving the alert, I'm still getting the "Empty" echo when the PHP page is loaded after the form submission. Does anyone know why is it happening? My final goal is just to send the text from the HTML file to the PHP file, and then to database (that is, the "responseText" is not really necessary, and it's here just with test purposes), but apparently, PHP is not really receiving what JS sends, while JS receives what PHP sends. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submit button is clicked and a submit event fires on the form.

The JavaScript is running. It is making an HTTP request to the PHP script with the data in it. Since you have forced it to be a synchronous request (don't do that, it locks up the event loop), the browser waits for the response before continuing. The JS is then processing the response, and alerting the value.

Then the form is submitted. It doesn't have a control with `name="q"`, so for the second request to the PHP script, `empty($example)` will always be true.

If you want to stop the form being submitted then call `preventDefault` on the event object.

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: The problem is that the form needs to be submitted, since it's a sign up form (of course, the one I posted here is just an example). I don't want people to need to send the required text separately, so it needs to be sent while the form is submitting. Do you know any way I can do this?
P.S.: I already set the XHR to true again. That was just me trying to find a way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Why are you using Ajax at all if you just want a normal form submission? Stick a name attribute in, take the JavaScript out, and you're good to go.

Comment: Good question! What I really need is to send a normal text to the PHP file through "post". As PHP doesn't have nothing like JavaScript's "innerHTML", I'm trying to accomplish this by Ajax, what, as you can see, is not working.
I used an input field in the example because I was trying to find out why my text wasn't being sent (so I decided to simplify the things).

Comment: If you want to change the existing page, then you can't use a normal form submission, that loads a new page. If you want to load a new page, then you just need to have your PHP output the page that you want with the data in the place you want it.

Comment: Well, I don't to change the existing page (that's why I don't need the "responseText"). Let me explain it better: my sign up form has a text field, and for this text field, I created a JS counter that writes in a "p" tag how many words and paragraphs have in the text being inserted in the text field. I need to send the result of this counter to the PHP file, so I can check if the text reaches a certain limit of words and paragraphs before sending it to database. That could be easily accomplished with JS, using the well known "innerHTML", but in PHP my searches didn't result in nothing simple.

Comment: Doing that will let the user bypass the count by overriding the value they are sending. Don't depend on the client to check that the data is good. Recount the words on the server by splitting the text field.

Comment: That's a good point. That's a big project I'm in, and there's so much things to think about that I had (stupidly) forgotten that the user could simply turn the JavaScript off and bypass the counter. Thank you for your answer(s)!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**1) in formdata-fields-control-test.js , make your script as a function :**

```
function testFunction() {
var q = document.getElementById("the-text").value;
var params = "q="+q;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200)) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
}
xhr.open("POST", "formdata-validation-test.php", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(params);
};
```

**2) in formdata-index-test.html , set action to empty and call the javascript function onsubmit :**

```
<form id="the-form" onsubmit="return testFunction()"  method="post"    action=""> 
<input type="text" id="the-text">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

the issue i think was with the form having an action and a onsubmit function together.

Comment: Maybe that works, since your point makes sense. Even though I decided to change what I was planning to do, thanks your answer!